# How to efficiently query very large MySQL table on primary key range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to query a very large MySQL table where the primary key takes on a range of values, but the query is too slow. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this, especially considering the following:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

runs instantaneously

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id between 1 and 6;
```

takes much longer.

The former expression won't work for me since I need values in the range [996737629,1006737629]. I am not able to modify the database.

Comment: What happens when you do `SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE id between 1 and 6;`?

Comment: Oh, the wonders of MySQL .. those really should have equivalent performance. Maybe the stats are off? (How they are off on the PK though I do not know..)

Comment: Have you run [`ANALYZE TABLE t1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html)?

Comment: @legohead actually that query will return farily quickly, larger ranges (few thousand say) time out.  the database is just too large (125mil rows) to be queried by anything other than a direct equality on primary key

Comment: @Bohemian I dont have write access :-/

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id > 1 AND id < 6` give? Also, are you sure you really need `*`?

Comment: @BenM I'm not actually using *, but the problem persists. This query performs the same as the one using 'BETWEEN'

Comment: Partitions might help, but since you're not able to modify the table structure in any way, I think you're stuck with the performance you have unfortunately.

Comment: @justaname can you ask your friendly DBA to do it for you?

Comment: @Bohemian yeah, perhaps so.

Comment: To what extent (if any) has your question simplified the queries that you are actually executing?  Are you seeing the observed performance difference when running the queries *exactly as shown*?  Specifics are really important here.  Also please let us see the `CREATE TABLE` statement and the query's execution plan?

Comment: Yeah, it may pay to chat to a person who can modify the database and see if there is a clustered index on that primary key. For a straight select into a table I don't believe there is anything else you can do to speed this one up!

Comment: @justaname . . . This could happen if the index on `id` where a hash index rather than a b-tree.